# Excel: Compare strings in column 1 and sum their values from column 2

Tags: excel-formula

I Have two columns of data. Column 1 has dates. Column 2 has value ranging from 1 - 5, so each Date will have a value associated with it on the same row. I am trying to compare dates in column 1 and Match same dates. I would then like to Sum the matched dates values together.

Edit: I am Sorry I assumed tagging Excel formula would imply I was looking for an excel formula that would fork best to try this. I am taking on a project on my own and have no support from others. Stack overflow is an amazing resources for people like myself with little experience to connect with experts. However the responses so far seem rude and unsympathetic to someone trying to learn a new approach to excel.

I tried to create this statement to find matching dates in column E and then multiply their values in column G. So far it just adds up column G.

=IF(MATCH(E2,E:E),SUM(G2,G:G),PRODUCT(G2,1))

Is their an easier formula to use? What does the =INDEX formula do, and would it help store the values on the rows of the matched dates?

Comment: So you're asking us to write your code for you? Sorry, that's not what this site is for. If you have a specific problem with something you've already written, then you can ask about it here. Please read this: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail and include a minimal example in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming ***Dates*** are in `Column G` with associated ***Values*** in `Column I` and dates to compare are in `Column K` then to get ***Sum*** of values of each date from `Column K` enter the following formula in `Cell L2`

```
=SUMIF($G$2:$G$21,K2,$I$2:$I$21)
```

Drag/Copy down as required. Change range as needed. See image for reference.

[image]

If anything is not clear let me know.

> **PS :** Now imagine if I write only the formula in my answer without any explanation or screen-shot. Will you be able to understand my answer. Probably No. So people here are not rude, its just we want sufficient information in question so that we can understand and help you better. We are here to ask and answer questions and help anybody in solving their problem provided we understand the problem and efforts from your side could be seen in solving your problem.